# Difference behaviour between ansible engine and ansible tower

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

```
- name: Verification de l'espace disponible dans le VG
  shell: /sbin/vgs --unit g --noheadings "{{ vg_name }}"| awk '{print $7}' | sed -e "s/^<//" | sed 's/g//'
  register: vg_space_available

- name: Check de la taille disque necessaire
  shell: /bin/echo "({{size_FS_syst01}}+{{size_FS_syst02}}+{{size_FS_syst03}}+{{size_FS_data01}}+{{size_FS_arch}})" | bc
  register: check_size_disk

- name: Espace disque insuffisant dans le VG
  fail:
    msg: "{{ ansible_hostname }} est un serveur physique. Pas de possibilite de rajouter un disque a chaud"
  when: vg_space_available.stdout|int < check_size_disk.stdout |int

- name: Espace disque suffisant dans le VG
  debug:
    msg: "Taille disponible suffisante dans le VG. Lancement de la creation du FS"
  when: vg_space_available.stdout|int > check_size_disk.stdout|int
```

The condition > < works perfectly for engine but not for tower...

Someone has an idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The command `vgs` gives a number with "," instead of ".". I corrected this by using `sed`.